# Remove first variable from query string via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have used the following code for rewriting my this url:

http://example.com/foldername/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from=new+york&search=hotel&location=north+park

to replace query string with '/' so it's http://example.com/foldername/sa/new+york/hotel/north+park?

I have achieved that with the following htaccess code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+foldername/New-York-Mills\.php\?ff_nm_from=([^&]+)&search=([^&\ ]+)&location=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /foldername/sa/%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^foldername/sa/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /Just-dial/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from=$1&search=$2&location=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /style.css [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\%2[Cc](.*)$ /$1$2?

RewriteRule ^foldername/sa/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/? foldername/sa/$1.php?ff_nm_from=$2&search=$3&location=$4
```

But I want my url like the following url. This means I want to remove first variable from url after query string.
http://example.com/foldername/New-York-Mills/hotel/north+park

How can it be done using the .htaccess file?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to rewrite `http://example.com/foldername/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from=new+york&search=hotel&location=north park` into `http://example.com/foldername/New-York-Mills/hotel/north+park`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can replace your first set of rewrite conditions and rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/foldername/New-York-Mills\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ff_nm_from=([^&]+)&search=([^&\ ]+)&location=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /foldername/New-York-Mills/%2/%3? [L,R=301]
```